# An alternative package of opende for indigo

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all

I have a ros-project which works nicely for all the previous distributions of ROS. I updated my ros and I've found out that opende is not supported anymore. Do you have any suggestions?

Best
Sina

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201517/an-alternative-package-of-opende-for-indigo/) by [sina](https://answers.ros.org/users/616/sina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ODE is available from Ubuntu as a system package. We've transitioned to using that from upstream. You should be able to do the same. You can use the rosdep key 'opende' to reference it.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0